# Как вывести число Y?

Tags: c++, математика

можете помочь с программой?Вот условие:Дано трехзначное целое число . Все цифры должны быть отличны от нуля.
Вывести новое трехзначное число , каждая цифра которого является остатком от деления числа 25 на соответствующую цифру числа .Должно быть выведено именно число , (оно может иметь меньше разрядов,если первые цифры получатся равными нулю), а не выведены на экран последовательно три цифры.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
     int x, y;
     cout << "Введите трехзначное число\n";
     cin >> x;
     int a, b, c;
     a = x % 25;
     b = x % 25;
     c = x % 25;
     int sum = a + b + c;
     cout << "Введите однозначное число\n";
     cin >> y;
     (sum % y != 0) ? cout << y << " " :cout<<"NO\n"; 
       system("pause");
       return 0;    
 }
```

Что тут нужно исправить?Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: нужно исправить все, потому что никакого отношения к вашей задаче ваш код не имеет! Просто пытаетесь обойти условие, что домашку надо попытаться сделать самому! Где в вашем условии говорится, что выводом может быть "NO"? Какое еще однозначное число вы пытаетесь ввести?!

Comment: Ну я уберу No.И исправлю вывод.

Comment: Какое уж тут "Ну..." - чем вы руководствовались при написании этого кода? Вопрос риторический, можете не отвечать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот:

```
int main() {
    int x;
    cout << "Введите трехзначное число: ";
    cin >> x;
    int d[3];

    for (int i = 0; x; x /= 10)
        d[i++] = 25 % (x % 10);

    x = d[2] * 100 + d[1] * 10 + d[0];
    cout << x;
    }
```

Но @Harry прав...

Comment: ,я согласен что домашку нужно делать самому,но я после c# ещё не привык к C++,поэтому такие проблемы и возникают.

Answer (score 1):

Вы неверно поняли условие.

Нужно для числа Х = 478 записать Y которое

```
Y1= 25%4=1
Y2= 25%7=4
Y3= 25%8=1
```

Получившееся число это Y=141. Вот почему там не может быть 0 в X.

```
 int a, b, c;
 a = 25 %(x/100);
 b = 25 %(x%100/10);
 c = 25 %(x%10);

 Y=a*100+b*10+c
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы просто складываете числа, а вам нужно ещё и умножить сотни и десятки на 100 и на 10 соответственно.

```cpp
 int sum = 100*a + 10*b + c;
```

Ёще увидел, что вы просто делите 3х значное число на 25, а не 25 на цифры числа х.

```cpp
a = 25 % (x / 100);
b = 25 % (x / 10 % 10);
c = 25 % (x % 10);
```

Comment: И какая *цифра* числа `x` у вас здесь, например? `(x / 10)`

Comment: Согласен. Ошибся. Сейчас поправлю.